# how can i validate to do not enter mobile number in description field of textarea using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can i validate to do not enter mobile number in description field of textarea using jquery

```js
     $('#jobpost').click(function () {
     var phoneno = /^\d{10}$/;  
     var discription=$('.nicEdit-main').html();

     if(discription.value.match(phoneno))
                     {
                         alert('gdfgdfg')
                       $("#froala-editor").parent().after("<div class='validation' style='color:red;margin-bottom: 20px;'>Please do not enter Mobile Number</div>");
                     $('#jobpost_form').attr('onsubmit','return false;');    
                     }

    });
```

Comment: mobile number or any phone number?

Comment: Whats the problem with your current script? Please make your question complete with why the current script is not correct.

Comment: @NikkoKhresna If You cont understand the script  then please dont comment....i'm already mention on my question heading about the issue...

Comment: How rude of you...For me trying to help you

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**.html**

```
 <div class="container">
    <form id="jobpost_form">
        <div class="row" id="froala-editor">
            <label>Enter Description</label>
            <textarea class="nicEdit-main" placeholder="write about yourself">    
            </textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" id="jobpost">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**.Js**

```
  $('#jobpost').click((e)=> {
    e.preventDefault();
    var phoneno = /[0-9]{10,12}$/;  // if +91 added it would be 12 
    var discription=$('.nicEdit-main').val();
    if(discription.match(phoneno))
    {
     $("#froala-editor").parent().after("<div class='validation' style='color:red;margin-bottom: 20px;'>Please do not enter Mobile Number</div>");
     $('#jobpost_form').attr('onsubmit','return false;');    
    }
});
```

**Note:**  You can modify as per your requirement. This given regular expression actually check the length of digits that should be equal or more than 10-12 digits to ensure as a mobile number.

**Feel free to comment for more help**

Comment: you can also use this on change value of input field, so button can perform his action well. And you can disable button until form validation not complete.

Comment: great done bro. @YugalKishore, if you are satisfied you can tick this answer and upvote me.

Answer (score 0):

if you trying to validate mobile-number in textarea field.

- use this pattern `/\d{10}/`
- change  this `$('.nicEdit-main').html();` to `$('.nicEdit-main').val();`
- change `discription.value.match(phoneno)`  to this  `discription.match(phoneno)`

In the pattern, use `^` and `$` only if you want to match only mobile-number.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question you can go through other solution where you can simply restrict user before typing a numeric value in the **textarea**.

And to do so you can use **keypress/input** function of textarea(input).

```
   <textarea id="txt" oninput="validateInput(event)"></textarea>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 $("#txt").keydown(function (e) {if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110]) !== -1 || (e.keyCode === 65 && (e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true)) || (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
            return;
        }
        if (e.key === '!' || e.key === '@' || e.key === '#' || e.key === '$' || e.key === '%' || e.key === '^' || e.key === '*' || e.key === '(' || e.key === ')') {
            return;
        }
        if ((e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57) || (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
});



 function validateInput(e) {
            var val = $("#txt").val();
            val = val.replace(/\d+/g, '');
            $("#txt").val(val);
        }
```

You can check the working demo [Right Here](https://js.do/rmohan20195/254834).

Hope this may help you because your question is very unique.